# Updating object properties in list comprehension way

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is that possible, in Python, to update a list of objects in list comprehension or some similar way?
For example, I'd like to set property of all objects in the list:

```
result = [ object.name = "blah" for object in objects]
```

or with `map` function

```
result = map(object.name = "blah", objects)
```

Could it be achieved without for-looping with property setting?

(Note: all above examples are intentionally wrong and provided only to express the idea)

Comment: I've been coding a lot of javascript recently where something like this would be possible: `const result = objects.map(object => object.name = 'blah')` so it's a little bit of a context switch going back to python.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Ultimately, assignment is a "Statement", not an "Expression", so it can't be used in a lambda expression or list comprehension.  You need a regular function to accomplish what you're trying.

There is a builtin which will do it (returning a list of `None`):

```
[setattr(obj,'name','blah') for obj in objects]
```

But **please don't use it.  Just use a loop.**  I doubt that you'll notice any difference in efficiency and a loop is so much more clear.

If you really need a 1-liner (although I don't see why):

```
for obj in objects: obj.name = "blah"
```

---

I find that most people want to use list-comprehensions because someone told them that they are "fast".  That's correct, but only for creating a new list.  Using a list comprehension for side-effects is unlikely to lead to any performance benefit and your code will suffer in terms of readability.  Really, the most important reason to use a list comprehension instead of the equivalent loop with `.append` is because it is easier to read.

Comment: I agree 100% that you should really just not do this, but if you must do this, at least encapsulate the transformation in to a function that returns a Falsey value and use an `if` condition in the comprehension to apply it, so you don't generate an entire new list when you just want to transform in place.

Comment: @sr2222 -- I suppose you *could* do that:  `[None for obj in objects if setattr(obj,'name','blah')]`, but that's even less clear than my version.  Persionally, I'd say the list of `None` is a lesser evil than the increased confusion from this approach.  But in any event -- Neither should be used.  use a loop :)

Comment: Well, list comprehensions shouldn't be used for side-effects, as it just makes code hard to read.  But if you are going to use a list comprehension for a side effect, it seems like you should at least try to do it in a way that doesn't produce a useless artifact.  As far as readability though, I don't really think either one is clear.  :)

Comment: I know this is crazy since the premise goes against Python, but consider using the `itertools` *consume* recipe, I believe it was created to take advantage of the speed advantages of iterators in this way, although a `for` loop is better of course