# Convert type of property of all elements in a list using one line for

Tags: python, list-comprehension

If I have the following class:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.isFoo = True
```

and I have a list of `foo` elements.
How can I convert the `isFoo` property of all the elements to be int and not bool in one line?

Something similar to:

```
[option.hoist_loads = int(element.isFoo) for element in foo_list]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating object properties in list comprehension way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650369/updating-object-properties-in-list-comprehension-way)

Answer (score 0):

I would add method in the class foo to change the `isFoo` from bool to an integer then return the instance.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.isFoo = True

    def change_foo_int(self):
        self.isFoo = int(self.isFoo)
        return self


spam = [foo(1, 2), foo(3, 4), foo(5, 6), foo(7, 8), foo(9, 10)]
spam = [foo_.change_foo_int() for foo_ in spam]
```